# how can I find files matching multiple extensions from current directory with a single command?

Tags: command-line

For example all files matching "*.doc" and "*.txt". I know how to find one extension type, but I need multiple without running multiple commands.

Comment: You can find the answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine tests in `find` using `-o` (OR)

```
find path/to/somedir \( -name '*.doc' -o -name '*.txt' \)
```

See `man find`, in particular